# Error while posting a message on wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a sample message on user's wall. But the `FB.ui` method does not execute and I get a message saying "An error occurred. Please try again later". This is the code inside the body:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
alert('hiee');   

 FB.init({appId: '259494234140448', status: true, cookie: true,
 xfbml: true});

 };
 (function() {

 var e = document.createElement('script'); 
 e.async = true;
 e.src = document.location.protocol +
 '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
 document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);

 }());
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function publish_to_wall(){  

    FB.ui({ method: 'stream.publish',    
        message: 'This is a simple post to appshack.tv'   });
    }
        </script>
}
<a href="javascript:publish_to_wall()">Publish to your wall</a>
```

Comment: have in mind that you can't use the 'message' param anymore. you have to use the 'description' param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot publish to a user's wall until that user authenticates your app.